# I can't get emails to my inbox, even though i can see a successful transaction in mailtrap

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-mail

i just sent an email using mailtrap on laravel, i can get the notifications on mailtrap, but the email does not get to the intended user emails. What could be the problem and how can i obtain a solution

I've tried changing the default "from" parameter to a real email address and yet the mails do not drop.

Comment: Who are you sending the email with?  You should check your logs in the SMTP server or however you are sending the email...

Answer (score 0):

Mailtrap is a fake dev server for testing your emails. It traps the email and doesn't forward it on to the intended user. Once you can see that it works and it looks correct, change to a real service like mailgun, reset your config, and it should get to the right place.

Comment: Mailgun is one of the drivers supported by Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail.